# How to keep all html elements with selector but drop all others?

Tags: python, lxml, lxml.html

I would like to get a HTML string without certain elements. However, upfront I just know which elements to keep but don't know which ones to drop.

Let's say I just want to keep all `p` and `a` tags inside the `div` with `class="A"`.

Input:

```html
<div class="A">
  <p>Text1</p>
  <img src="A.jpg">
  <div class="sub1">
    <p>Subtext1</p>
  </div>
  <p>Text2</p>
  <a href="url">link text</a>
</div>
<div class="B">
  ContentDiv2
</div>
```

Expected output:

```html
<div class="A">
  <p>Text1</p>
  <p>Text2</p>
  <a href="url">link text</a>
</div>
```

If I'd know all the selectors of all other elements I could just use `lxml`'s `drop_tree()`. But the problem is that I don't know `['img', 'div.sub1', 'div.B']` upfront.

Example with `drop_tree()`:

```py
import lxml.cssselect
import lxml.html

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html_str)

elements_drop = ['img', 'div.sub1', 'div.B']
for j in elements_drop:
    selector = lxml.cssselect.CSSSelector(j)
    for e in selector(tree):
        e.drop_tree()

output = lxml.html.tostring(tree)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear; please edit your question and add to your html string another `<div>` sibling to the the `<div>` with `class="A"`, but with another class, and then show exactly your expected output given this new html string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure I understand correctly, but it seems like you may be looking for something resembling this:

```py
target = tree.xpath('//div[@class="A"]')[0]
to_keep = target.xpath('//p | //a')
for t in target.xpath('.//*'):
    if t not in to_keep:
        target.remove(t) #I believe this method is better here than drop_tree()
print(lxml.html.tostring(target).decode())
```

The output I get is your expected output.

Comment: Perfect that works! Thanks. We can also use xpath for `to_keep` so we can use more complex selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below. The idea is to clean the root and add the required sub elements.

Note that *no external lib is required*.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

html = '''<div class="A">
  <p>Text1</p>
  <img src="A.jpg"/>
  <div class="sub1">
    <p>Subtext1</p>
  </div>
  <p>Text2</p>
  <a href="url">link text</a>
  ContentDiv2
</div>'''
root = ET.fromstring(html)
p_lst = root.findall('./p')
a_lst = root.findall('./a')
children = list(root)
for c in children:
    root.remove(c)
for p in p_lst:
    p.tail = ''
    root.append(p)
for a in a_lst:
    a.tail = ''
    root.append(a)
root.text = ''
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div class="A">
   <p>Text1</p>
   <p>Text2</p>
   <a href="url">link text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Nice solution if someone doesn't want to use external libs! I'm using `lxml` anyways, so I don't have a problem with @jack-fleeting solution.